# Android studio: pause and resume session on webview

Tags: java, android, android-studio, session, webview

Is there a way to keep users logged in even after restart without saving username and password locally?. I just want to pause the session when the app is closed then resume when it is opened.

Tried both:

```
    myWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    myWebView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
```

Also tried CookieManager and managed to do what I want but for some reason, it stopped working and keeps logging out users when app exits(I'm still new and I do not know what happened and am not able to fix it). So I'm trying to find a different approach to do this.

My MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public DrawerLayout dLayout;
private WebView myWebView;
public ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle;

public void setActionBarTitle(String title) {
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setTitle("Updates");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //CREATE A FOLDER
    File file = this.getBaseContext().getExternalFilesDir("downloads");
    if (!file.exists())
        file.mkdir();
    setNavigationDrawer(); // call method
    dLayout = findViewById(R.id.my_drawer_layout);
    actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, dLayout, R.string.nav_open, R.string.nav_close);

    dLayout.addDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);
    actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();

    // to make the Navigation drawer icon always appear on the action bar
    Objects.requireNonNull(getSupportActionBar()).setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    myWebView = findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
    WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    myWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    myWebView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    myWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());

    String url = "http://192.168.43.105/public_html/central/updates.php";
    myWebView.loadUrl(url);
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        public void onReceivedError(WebView webView, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Oh no! " + description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

        public void onPageFinished(WebView webView, String url) {
            CookieManager.getInstance().flush();
        }


    });
    myWebView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
    myWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    myWebView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
    myWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(false);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptCookie(true);

    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

            //Do you have cookies?
            Log.d("logged", "url: " + url + ", cookies: " + CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(url));
        }

    });

    String url = "http://192.168.43.105/public_html/central/updates.php";
    myWebView.loadUrl(url);
```

Finally made it work(again, I probably deleted a line accidentally). My website creates a cookie named "logged" after user logged in, which contains the name of the user. Added the code in the onCreate.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the working codes that I use. Try these.

```
 /*Webview settings.*/
```

public static String DATABASES_SUB_FOLDER = "/databases";

```
    public void setWebSettings(WebSettings webSettings) {
        this.webSettings = webSettings;
        /*Accept Cookie*/
        CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
        cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(true);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            cookieManager.setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(webview, true);
        }
        final String filesDir = getFilesDir().getPath();
        final String databaseDir = filesDir.substring(0, filesDir.lastIndexOf("/")) + DATABASES_SUB_FOLDER;

        webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webSettings.setDisplayZoomControls(false);
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.OFF);
        webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webSettings.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
        //   webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
//        webSettings.setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 10; SM-G970F) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3396.81 Mobile Safari/537.36");
        webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
        webSettings.setAllowContentAccess(true);
        webSettings.supportZoom();
          if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
            webSettings.setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);
        }
        webSettings.setGeolocationEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);
        webSettings.setDatabaseEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
//        webSettings.setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
        webSettings.setSaveFormData(true);
        webSettings.setSavePassword(true);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_HARDWARE_ACCELERATED, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_HARDWARE_ACCELERATED);


        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            // chromium, enable hardware acceleration
            webview.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
        } else {
            // older android version, disable hardware acceleration
            webview.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
        }

        /*acces file url*/
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16) {
            webSettings.setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
            webSettings.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        }

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 18) {
            webSettings.setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);
        }

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19) {
            webSettings.setDatabasePath(databaseDir);
        }

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
            CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(webview, true);
        }

    }
```